# Hadoop Reducer Driver Communication

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

The output of my chained mapreduce is an intermediate result. When my iteration found a solution I want to "send" it to the driver. How can I achieve this?

I tried to use the `Configuratuion`, but it didnt work. Seems like its just distributed, not synced to the nodes...

Comment: What constitutes a solution to your problem? I mean what data type? If numeric, you could set it in a counter and get it when the current iteration finishes from the Driver.

Comment: Its a simple string .